# Should I write a function on chain in smart contract or off chain?

Tags: ethereum, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, web3js

I'm confused about in what case should I put function logic on-chain in smart contract? or off-chain in frontend as ethers.js/ web3js etc.

In web2, I think no matter I put the function in frontend or backend, they have same performance.

Here is a example on-chain:

```
// give an address bonus token if its current balance is more than 0. 
// Maximum is 100. 

function bonus(address anyAddress) public {
    if (balanceOf(anyAddress) >= 0 && balanceOf(anyAddress) < 100)  {
        _mint(anyAddress, 100 - balanceOf(anyAddress));
    } 
}
```

Obviously, I can use frontend logic to code the a function by calling the _mint() and balanceOf() function on-chain, which can perform the same result, and maybe save gas.

So, why should I put packaged function on chain?

Comment: Where is that `_mint` function from? it is from another contract, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, it inherited from OpenZeppelin, as well as balanceOf function.

Answer (score 1):

It's often good practice to include validation logic in the contract. And for better user experience, you can duplicate the validation on the frontend.

Mind that technically skilled users can execute the contract function using other ways (from a custom script, through another contract, ...) - not just from their MetaMask wallet through your frontend app.